# Passing std vector as reference: no matching function to call

Tags: c++, vector

I can't see what's wrong with my code. I have a an std::vector which is a private member of my class Foo. It is not declared as const, even when the error the compiler gives suggests so.

(At Foo.h)

```
private:
std::vector<std::string> tableBackup;
```

I'm calling a function (from Foo.cpp):

```
BackupTable(this->tableBackup);
```

This method is into DatabaseLoad.cpp and .h:

```
public:
void BackupTable(std::vector<std::string> &tableBackup);
```

Defined as:

```
void DatabaseLoad::BackupTable(std::vector<std::string> &tableBackup){
//whatever...
}
```

I'm getting the following error when I call the method from Foo.cpp:

```
No matching function for call to 'DatabaseLoad::BackupTable(const std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > &)'
```

What's the problem? Currently using C++11, but I guess this has nothing to do with that.

Comment: As it's member already, why pass to function again? Btw, it's whinging about `const`

Comment: @billz, there are two classes there.

Comment: Show the calling member function as well (I'd wager it's `const`-qualified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be calling `BackupTable(this->tableBackup);` inside a member function which is qualified as `const`. This means that `this` is of type `const Whatever*`, and thus all data members are implicitly `const`-qualified inside this member function as well. So they cannot be bound to a non-`const` reference.

You have two sane options:

1. If `BackupTable` does not modify its argument, it should accept it as `const &` instead of just `&`.
2. If it does modify its argument, it means the calling function modifies its `this` object, so it should not be marked as `const`.

A third (far less likely) option is that `tableBackup` is actually an implementation details of your class and the fact that it changes does not affect the "logical `const`ness" of the class. If that is so, you can mark it as `mutable` (that way, even `const` functions will be able to modify it). At the same time, you **must** introduce some form of synchronisation mechanism (e.g. a mutex) whenever you access the mutable `tableBackup` (or any mutable member). The reason is that all of the standard library expects `const` operations to be thread-safe. An emerging idiom for this is adding a private member like this:

```
mutable std::mutex mutables;
```

And locking `mutables` whenever you access (even just for reading!) a mutable member.

Comment: And be aware that this idiom recapitulates  Java `synchronized`. So you'd better make sure you don't call any unknown code under the lock, or you *will* eventually suffer lock inversion ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the `BackupTable` function in a context where the `DatabaseLoad` object is `const`-qualified, therefore the compiler is expecting a call to a `const`-reference.

If you are not planning on modifying the vector, you should declare the function as:

```
void BackupTable(const std::vector<std::string>& tableBackup);
```

Answer (score 2):

I can guess that you are calling BackupTable from const method of Foo class

Answer (score 1):

I think that 'this' is const in ' BackupTable(this->tableBackup);'. You call the ' BackupTable' in a 'Foo() const' function.